# Understanding Unique-SVP and Kannan's Embedding

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

[image: Kannan's Embedding]

I am trying to understand the Kannan embedding technique. But I am confused about the formation of the **B'** and the finding of the short vector inside that basis. How does this basis matrix in the algorithm produce a lattice? Or more specifically why a uSVP instance consist of a vector(**e**^T) and an integer(M)?

Thanks.

Comment: How do I use Kannan embedding approach to find ECDSA private keys of a blockchain using 256-bit hash function algorithms such as SHA256 and Keccak256? what are the open source tools to run Sage along with ECDSA? Are there any open source homomorphic encryption/decryption tools to test LWE and DLWE in order to break various post-quantum cryptosystems and block ciphers of public blockchains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns of matrix $B'$ generate a lattice $\Lambda'=\{\mathbf v'\in\mathbb Z^{n+1}\}$ where the first $n$ entries form a vector which differs from a vector of $\Lambda$ by some multiple of $\mathbf e$ and the last entry is the same multiple of $M$. We also need some guarantee that $\mathbf e$ is shorter than the shortest vector of $\Lambda$ by some amount and that $\mathbf {As}$ is the closest vector to $\mathbf b$.

$M$ is not necessarily an integer, but is some value such that e.g. $M=||\mathbf e||$ when we know $||\mathbf e||<\lambda_1/2$ where $\lambda_1$ is the length of the shortest vector of $\Lambda$. It follows that the vector $(\mathbf e, M)^T$ has length at most $\sqrt 2M<\lambda_1/\sqrt 2$. This is shorter than any vector of the form $(\mathbf x, 0)^T$ which corresponds to a vector $\mathbf x$ of $\Lambda$ and so is of length at least $\lambda_1$. It is shorter than any other vector of the form $(\mathbf y, M)^T$ by the definition of the closest vector. It is also short than any vector of the form $(\mathbf z, kM)^T$ for any $|k|\ge 2$ as such a vector has length at least $|k|M>\sqrt 2 M$ based on the final component. It follows that $(\mathbf e, M)$ is the unique shortest vector of $\Lambda'$.

Comment: Dear Daniel thanks for the answer. I figure out some points of this problem with the help of your answer. But I have another question. In this explanation I cannot imagine the graphical intuition of the lattice. We use **B** and target vector **b** to obtain **B'** but why we increase the dimension of **B'** with zero's and M? Is it about unique-SVP instance? If so, why unique-SVP instance consist of a vector and a number(say M)?

Comment: If we did not add an extra row we would have an $n$ dimensional lattice with $n+1$ generators with determinant dividing $q$ but less than $q$. This would almost certainly have vectors that are shorter than $e$ but are of the form $\mathbf {Ax}+k\mathbf e$ for some (unknown) $k$. Instead we embed $\Lambda$ in this larger lattice and weight the extra dimension in order to single out the $k=1$ case.